# Accessing object returned from GraphQL using curl

Tags: php, json, object, curl

I have returned data using GraphQL / curl that looks like this:

```
{
  "data" : {
    "publisher" : {
      "contracts" : {
        "totalCount" : 11,
        "count" : 1,
        "resultList" : [
```

I want to get the resultList array and keep getting an error 'Warning: Attempt to read property "data" on string' when trying to do $result->data to move into the first object. What am I doing wrong?

My variable from the curl request is $result.

Update: I HAVE TRIED DECODING AND THE RETURNED DATA IS OF TYPE INT? How?

```
function getData($data_String){

    $endpoint = "https://programs.api.cj.com/query";
    $authToken = "pass";
    $qry = '{"query":"{ publisher { contracts(publisherId: \"xxxxxxx\", limit: 1, filters: {advertiserId: \"'.$advertiser_id.'\"}) { totalCount count resultList { startTime endTime status advertiserId programTerms { id name specialTerms { name body } isDefault actionTerms { id actionTracker { id name description type } lockingMethod { type durationInDays } performanceIncentives { threshold { type value } reward { type commissionType value } currency } commissions { rank situation { id name } itemList { id name } promotionalProperties { id name } rate { type value currency } } } } } } } }","variables":null}';

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$authToken;

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $qry);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);


    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    $data = json_decode($result);


    return $data;

}
```

Comment: You need to show us how you decoded it and how you verified that it was an int.  All you've shown us here is an incomplete JSON object, which doesn't give us much to go on.

Comment: have added more.

Comment: Try setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true` instead of `0`.

Comment: thats done it! thanks so much. Would you mind explaining what that actually does?

Comment: As it says [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php): _"CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFEER - true to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it directly."_ In cases like this (or in any case really), don't just set options without knowing what they actually do. Always start with reading the manual.

Comment: wise words, will take on board. thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure to check if the result is a valid json.

Then use json_decode to get an object

```
$result = json_decode($result);
if (is_object($result)) {
  if (!empty($result->data->publisher->contracts->resultList)) {
     $resultList = $result->data->publisher->contracts->resultList;
  }
} else {
  // Log or something
   error_log("json decode return: " . print_r($result, true))
}
```

Comment: yeah its hitting the error